# parallelism.default not working for Flink Standalone Kubernetes Session Mode

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming, minikube

I'm following this documentation

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/

about how to setup a standalone kubernetes session cluster using minikube.
I've already installed minikube and I'm able to create pods.
In `flink-configuration-configmap.yaml` file I set the properties

```
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 4
parallelism.default: 2
```

This properties are correctly read from Flink Dashboard:
[image]

But when I submit a Flink job, all tasks have parallelism to 1:
[image]
What I execpted is that task should have parallelism 2.

Can you help me to understand what's wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The default parallelism can be overridden during submission, or by the job itself. I would look in those places to see if the parallelism is being set explicitly.

Comment: Setting the parallelism explicitily on job submission works as well as setting paralelism at operator level or job level. I'd like to understand why default value is not considered if parallelism is not explicitly set.